# Flot graphs were not visible in IE family

Tags: jquery

I am using Flot graphs on my webpage but for the IE family of browsers they are not visible. After searching on Google I found a solution/fix for **IE-9**, but none for **IE-7** or **IE-8**. Does anyone know of a fix for those two versions of IE?

Here is the link where I found the fix for **IE-9**: [Flot graphs were not visible in IE 9](http://drupal.org/node/1479748)

Comment: If it works with _canvas_ element, those archaic browsers do not support it.

Comment: @badZoke if u goto that link u can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
```